# ASP.NET Core with mobile application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, design-patterns, asp.net-core, architecture

I'm working on a project that needs a web site and mobile application. User can interact with our system through website or mobile application. Now the real problem I'm facing is how should I structure it?
Options I considered:

1. ASP.NET Core website + Mobile application --> ASP.NET Core REST API
2. ASP.NET Core as website + rest endpoints <-- Mobile application

Comment: I would create services to distribute the data from the repositories and modify it and create endpoints for the API + ordinary routes that will return the templates for the web. And in both actions call the service that will give me all desired data.

Answer (score 0):

You should always expose your backend functionality through rest endpoints. This way any consumer like ASP.NET website or Mobile application can consume it using their rest client.

Exposing it through rest will enable client written in any technology to consume.

So your first option seems to be the suitable one.